# How to filter a stream of tuple with Apache Edgent

Tags: java, apache-edgent

I created a source function according to this [manual](http://edgent.incubator.apache.org/recipes/recipe_source_function.html).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DirectProvider dp = new DirectProvider();
    Topology top = dp.newTopology();

    final URL url = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=BAC+COG+FCX&f=snabl");

    TStream<String> linesOfWebsite = top.source(queryWebsite(url));
}
```

Now I'd like to filter this stream. I had something like this in mind:

```
TStream<Iterable<String>> simpleFiltered = source.filter(item-> item.contains("BAX");
```

Which is not working. Does anybody has an idea how to filter the stream? I don't want to change the request url to do the filtering upfront.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from the info provided.  `dp.submit(top)` is needed to run the topology. The filter code isn't specifying an item that occurs using the URL that's being specified.  e.g.,

```
...
TStream<String> linesOfWebsite = top.source(queryWebsite(url));
linesOfWebsite.print(); // show what's received

TStream<String> filtered = linesOfWebsite.filter(t -> t.contains("BAC"));
filtered.sink(t -> System.out.println("filtered: " + t));

dp.submit(top);  // required
```